# How to plot an inverse function in python?

Tags: python

I have the functions sigma(a) and g(a, sigma), where g is actually only a function of 'a'. I'd like to invert the dependence of sigma so as to have a(sigma) and then g(a, sigma) being a function of sigma. I don't need the expression of a(sigma) (it may be terrible!), I just need the plot of this new g. Can someone help me? Here's the definition of sigma and g:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.linspace(0, 10, 10000)

def sigma(a):
    sigma = 1 + 2*a*(np.sinh(a) - np.sin(a))/(np.cosh(a) + np.cos(a))
    return sigma

def g(a, sigma):
    g = 2*sigma*(np.cosh(a*(sigma - 1)/(sigma + 1)) + np.cos(a*(sigma - 1)/(sigma + 1)))/((sigma + 1)*(np.cosh(a) + np.cos(a)))
    return g
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is dependent on what you would like to plot 'g' against. Viewing the 'g' values against the list of 'a' values, to create a simple **line plot**, would be done like this:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt # Plotting library

def sigma(a):
    sigma = 1 + 2*a*(np.sinh(a) - np.sin(a))/(np.cosh(a) + np.cos(a))
    return sigma

def g(a, sigma):
    g = 2*sigma*(np.cosh(a*(sigma - 1)/(sigma + 1)) + np.cos(a*(sigma - 1)/(sigma + 1)))/((sigma + 1)*(np.cosh(a) + np.cos(a)))
    return g

# Create an array of 'a' values:
a_list = np.linspace(0, 10, 10000)

# Get the sigma value for each corresponding 'a' value:
sigma_list = [sigma(a=value) for value in a_list]

# Get the g value for each corresponding 'a' value and 'sigma' value:
g_list = [g(a=value, sigma=i) for i, value in enumerate(a_list)]

# plot using matplotlib:
plt.figure()
plt.plot(a_list, g_list, label='g')
plt.show()
```

If you would like a **surface plot** (taking both 'sigma' and 'a' into account), you will have to do the following (first, limiting the size of your a value array):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt # Plotting library

def sigma(a):

    return 1 + 2*a*(np.sinh(a) - np.sin(a))/(np.cosh(a) + np.cos(a))

def g(a, sigma):

    return 2*sigma*(np.cosh(a*(sigma - 1)/(sigma + 1)) + np.cos(a*(sigma - 1)/(sigma + 1)))/((sigma + 1)*(np.cosh(a) + np.cos(a)))

# Create an array of 'a' values:
a_list = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

# Get the sigma value for each corresponding 'a' value:
sigma_list = [sigma(a=value) for value in a_list]

# Create the coordinate matrix using np.meshgrid, and then find the values for 'z' using g():
X_axis, Y_axis = np.meshgrid(a_list, sigma_list)
Z_axis = g(a=X_axis, sigma=Y_axis)

plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_wireframe(X_axis, Y_axis, Z_axis)
plt.show()
```